# Unable to expose Docker API on 127.0.0.1:2375 on Windows

Tags: docker

If I have an active checkbox on the tls field, then an error occurs at docker start

[image: checkbox]

[image: Error]

I tried to find what this program is, but I could not

`nestat -o` command dont give this port

Help please find this program

Comment: Where the help text says "use with caution", it is a _massive_ security exposure to enable this, and I would probably _never_ check this box.  Why do you think you need it?

Comment: debugging what process can occupy that port may be a very case specific task. Universal fix to this would be to expose API by different port using docker daemon settings https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file

Comment: You need this to use the xdebug

Comment: @David Maze, yes, I absolutelly sure that I need to use it (+ I don`t care about any security). Do you have solution for above problem?

Comment: @lGSMl, I dont see on your links the information which could helps to solve the problem. Could you explain how it could helps, please?

Comment: First link explains docker daemon sockets mechanic and how to reassign default 2375 port to something else. Second link explains how to make this change permanent using settings file. It is all there with links pointing to the specific ref.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug from latest docker desktop version. Confirm if the port 2375 is used by  com.docker.proxy.exe. If so, then you can consider the warning as a false alarm.
For more, see here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/10701